# AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights concatenation values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I would like to move **val2** from second row to first row and show just one row for this @timestamp value. There are have same @timestamp value.

What I have for now

| @timestamp | id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-04T12:21:51.085+03:00 | test-id | val1 |  |
| 2022-02-04T12:21:51.085+03:00 |  |  | val2 |

What I expect:

| @timestamp | id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-04T12:21:51.085+03:00 | test-id | val1 | val2 |

Here is my query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message 
| parse @message /-(?<requestId>([A-Za-z0-9]{5,})).*id=(?<id>[^,]+).*x-value1=(?<value1>([A-Za-z0-9-_,()!@#$%<>:*?\s]+[.]{1}[A-Za-z]{3,4}))/ 
| filter strcontains(@message, 'x-value1=') or strcontains(@message, concat(requestId, ') Method request body before transformations: {')) 
| parse @message "Method request body before transformations: {*}" as value2 
| display @timestamp, id, value1, value2
```

Comment: Logs insights can only operate on a single message at a time.

Comment: Are you able to solve this?